# Confused by Boxing. Casting -1 to Int64 throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, language-design, language-features

Ok I must be overlooking something extremely simple but I am lost.

Given this

```
object val = -1;
var foo = (Int32)(val);
var bar = (Int64)(val);
```

The cast to Int64 throws and InvalidCastException.

I recognize this is related to some strangeness with boxing but I don't understand the reasoning.

From what I understand val is boxed as Int32 on the first line.

Then when I try to cast as something other than Int32 InvalidCastException is thrown. I suppose this means that I am trying to unbox val as Int64 when it is actually an Int32?

Still seems strange. Couldn't the cast unbox the value and then try to perform the cast?

Something like (Obviously this is horribly oversimplified, maybe the boxed type isn't known so this isn't possible?):

```
object val = -1;
Int32 unboxed = (Int32)(val);
var bar = (Int64)(unboxed);
```

Someone (read: Eric Lippert) School me on the reasoning behind this.

**UPDATE:** From Eric's Blog that Reed posted a link to this is the succinct answer I was looking for

*"...This would be a huge amount of code to generate, and it would be very slow. The code is of course so large that you would want to put it in its own method and just generate a call to it. Rather than do that by default, and always generate code that is slow, large and fragile, **instead we’ve decided that unboxing can only unbox to the exact type.** If you want to call the slow method that does all that goo, it’s available – you can always call Convert.ToInt32, which does all that analysis at runtime for you. We give you the choice between “fast and precise” or “slow and lax”, and the sensible default is the former. If you want the latter then call the method...."*

Comment: This is something extremely non-simple.  It trips up a lot of people...

Comment: Reed is right; this gets asked several times a week on SO. It was asked twice yesterday.

Comment: So, I am clearly lame for asking the same question that everyone else asks and not searching first. I find it interesting that this still gets 6 up votes if it is such a common question. Apparently the default behavior isn't the most obvious behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because you can't unbox and perform a conversion in a single operation.  You must unbox the Int32 value into an Int32, and then subsequently convert its type.

Because of that, this requires the object to be unboxed, then converted to Int64:

```
object val = -1;
int foo = (Int32)val;
Int64 bar = (Int64)(Int32)val;
```

Eric Lippert covered this in detail on his blog post titled [Representation and Identity](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/).

Comment: Awesome, Eric Lippert by proxy :) You rock

Comment: Another way to write: `Int64 a = -1; object o = a; Int64 b = (Int64)o;` Thanks Reed!

Comment: Could people please stop saying *cast* when they mean *conversion*? There is no “casting” between integer types; they are being *converted*. (It is unfortunate that C# uses the same syntax for both.)

Comment: @Timwi: I agree with you, but you're fighting an uphill battle. I prefer to reserve "cast" to mean the actual compile time text of the cast operator in code, and "conversion" for the runtime operation of converting one type to another. But most people do not make that distinction.