# Unboxing -1 and casting to Nullable<int> using generics yields InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, generics, casting, unboxing

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321975/generic-method-to-read-data-from-datareader) I found a generic extension method which returns a default value if a value read by an `SqlDataReader` is `null` or `DBNull.Value`, and the correctly converted value otherwise. I implemented it like this:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
  object val = reader[columnName];
  if (val == null || val == DBNull.Value)
  {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  return (T)val;
}
```

The examples mentioned below the method in the post linked above don't use the correct syntax, but nevertheless suggest that this should also work with nullable types such as `int?`.

However, I read a nullable `int` column from the database like this:

```
MyProperty = reader.GetValueOrDefault<int?>("SomeColumnName")
```

where debug mode shows me that `val` is `-1` and `T` is `int?`, but I get an InvalidCastException. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926654/confused-by-boxing-casting-1-to-int64-throws-invalidcastexception) I figured it's because unboxing and casting can't be performed in a single operation (`val` is of type `object` holding a `short` value), but what can I do to make it work in my case? Since it's a generic method, I wouldn't know how to manually unbox it before doing the conversion.

Comment: MyProperty = reader.GetValueOrDefault<int>("SomeColumnName")

Comment: @TimSchmelter That still doesn't work. I guess it's because the -1 value is treated as a `short`, but I can't write `reader.GetValueOrDefault<short>` because it could actually hold a larger number in the database.

Comment: @InvisiblePanda No. What is the database column type? If database can hold a large value, it will not be of type `short` in `SqlDataReader`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You actually pointed me in the right direction. See my comment to the accepted answer below. The type was changed from `int` to `smallint` in the database and I have to change the model POCOs accordingly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a really good answer, you need to post [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If a cast to `int` fails, then the boxed value isn't an `int`. You should be able to see in the debugger what it actually is.

That said, the `Convert` class is a lot more sophisticated about conversions; the cast will require an *exact* match, i.e. the boxed value must be an `int` (the literal `-1` would be an `int`, but in your case the value's coming from who-knows-where and easily could be a `short` or `long` or whatever).

So instead of the cast, a call e.g. to `Convert.ToInt32()` would work better.

In your case, with the generic method (i.e. the type is unknown at compile-time), the `Convert.ChangeType()` method is probably more appropriate:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
  object val = reader[columnName];
  if (val == null || val == DBNull.Value)
  {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think `-1` can be an `uint`. :)

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the answer. I actually tried creating such an example, but I couldn't reproduce the problem because I didn't understand it well enough :/ That is, I tried to reproduce it by doing stuff like `(int?)((short)-1)` and similar, but never got the above error. Now having read the above comments, I could have done so.

Comment: Actually, I don't want (or didn't want, rather) to convert to `int`, but somehow directly return `int?`. Summarizing the comments below the original post, I found out what the problem was. It's a database "under construction", and the column got changed to `smallint`, so that's the reason I'm getting a `short` value. . . I'll accept your answer anyway, as it provides useful input for me, and because noone could have pointed directly to the actual silly cause of the problem ;)

Comment: @InvisiblePanda: okay, thanks. Glad to hear you tracked the issue down. I should point out that in the generic case, the `ChangeType()` method makes more sense than the `ToInt32()` I proposed. I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: The issue with Convert.ChangeType() is that it's uber slow compared to just casting.  I was hoping for another answer, but it looks like I will just have to find a way to control the type that is returned from the reader (by doing a cast in my SQL for example).